# How can I solve the concurrency problem in a REST service in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

I've a Spring Boot project.

Imagine two APIs that accept the same object as input to do different things with it.
Before performing the action, each API validates the object, in particular there's a numeric field called progressiveNr, this number is basically used to understand the progression of requests for a specific voucher (without going into details, if it's not clear I'll discuss it).

Each API checks if the progressiveNr is correct based on the Voucher, so you can't send me progressiveNrs 1, 2, 4, 3 but it has to be sequentially.

That's what happened, the client called the 2 APIs milliseconds apart:
API 1 {requestId: 196, voucherId: 1, progressiveNr: 2}, API 2 {requestId: 197, voucherId: 1, progressiveNr: 3}.

For requestId 197 we gave the error "progressiveNr must be 2".
This is because, precisely while the 196 was processing, it was still in the validation phase and therefore had not yet performed any insert, the other API was called with the 197 with progressiveNr=3 which however, given that the 196 was not yet during the insert phase, the table rightly still showed progressiveNr=1 and therefore gave an error saying I expect progressiveNr=2.

Searching on the internet I found locks as a solution but I'm not clear how to apply it..

These are the methods called by the controller

```
    @Override
    @LogExecutionTime(printArgs = true, printResponse = true)
    public ResponseDTO subve(List<RequestSubveDTO> richieste) {
        List<ScartoTracciatoConnexa> daScartare = new ArrayList<>();

        //requests subve validation
        richieste.forEach(request -> {
            ScartoTracciatoConnexa sTC = validateSubve(request);

            if (sTC != null) daScartare.add(sTC);
        });

        //do other things

        //do the action
        asyncService.subve(richieste, daScartare);

        return new ResponseDTO(EsitiCodes.REQUEST_ACCEPTED);
    }

    private ScartoTracciatoConnexa validateSubve(RequestSubveDTO request) {
        try {
            validatorService.validateSubve(request);
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            return generaScarto(request, request.getNumVoucher(), SUBVE, e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @LogExecutionTime(printArgs = true, printResponse = true)
    public ResponseDTO renew(List<RequestRenewDTO> richieste) {
        List<ScartoTracciatoConnexa> daScartare = new ArrayList<>();

        //requests renew validation
        richieste.forEach(request -> {
            ScartoTracciatoConnexa sTC = validateRenew(request);

            if (sTC != null) daScartare.add(sTC);
        });

        //do other things

        //do the action
        asyncService.renew(richieste, daScartare);

        return new ResponseDTO(EsitiCodes.REQUEST_ACCEPTED);
    }

    private ScartoTracciatoConnexa validateRenew(RequestRenewDTO request) {
        try {
            validatorService.validateRenew(request);
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            return generaScarto(request, request.getNumVoucher(), RENEW, e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and this is my validatorService:

```
    @LogExecutionTime
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void validateRenew(RequestRenewDTO dto) throws InvalidRequestException {
        //Other validations

        //progressiveNr validation
        int lastProgNr = myObjectService.getLastProgNumByVoucherId(dto.getVoucherId()) + 1;

        if (lastProgNr != dto.getProgressiveNr())
            throw new InvalidRequestException();
    }

    //THE SAME FOR validateSubve(RequestSubveDTO dto)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your service supposed to tell the difference between "call with progressiveNr=3 was too early" and "call with progressiveNr=2 was never sent"?

Comment: In what sense? it is a check in the db on a field that is updated as soon as the validation is passed, so in the db there is 1, the request arrives with progressive number 2, everything is ok -> I insert 2 in the db, then the request arrives with progressive number 3, all ok -> I enter 3. The problem here is that while I'm doing the validation for the progressive number 2 they call me the other API with progressive number 3 so in db it still shows as 1 and gives an error.

Comment: But if the call with p.n.=2 was never made, the call with p.n.=3 *should* produce an error.  How do you tell the difference between these scenarios?

Comment: In that case it's ok to produce an error. I can tell the difference because the client wrote me what happened and I saw the log

Comment: My point is: how is the PROGRAM supposed to distinguish between these 2 situations, since it needs to behave differently in each?

Comment: The program can’t distinguish between these 2 situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is synchronous calls, it shouldn't be possible for your client to break the contract. It broke it if both request were sent at the same time and not synchronously. A client shouldn't be able to decide the state of your voucher without asking for it first.

So you answer a 400 Bad Request for the requestId 197 and 200 OK for the requestId196.
You should not struggle to implement bizarre stuff trying to guess what your client was willing to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Locks and "Blocking" is only relevant when the two services are *actually* processing at the same time and holding the locks. But what if a request to service 3 comes a whole second (or 10!) before service 2. There is no way for service 2 to be holding a lock (to block service 3) when it's not even running yet..

"Waiting" is more so what would be relevant here.. But you need to ask yourself how long should service 3 wait to see if service 2 completed?

If you want to have services wait for their predecessor then each service would need to perform re-checks to see if the prior service has completed or fail if it reaches a timeout.

Alternatively, *and possibly the better solution*, you can just specify in the API that a request for service 3 MUST NOT be sent until a response confirms that service 2 has completed successfully.

Even if they do call service 1 then service 2 there's not really a guarantee that service 1 made it there first. So the order they call the services gives no guarantees of the order they will be processed in, unless they wait for confirmation that prior services have completed successfully.

---

Even if you did try to use locks they wouldn't work across VMs. So if your services were behind a load balancer the separate instances wouldn't be able to block each other with Java locks. Database locks would be your only option in that case. This is still mostly irrelevant since what you're asking for is effectively a "grace period" for services and "waiting" is really your only option if that's what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Java Phaser or ReEntrant Lock should help here.